# Dynamic Parameters - with Dynamic ValidateSet

Tags: powershell, dynamic, parameters

I have a script that I've been working on to provide parsing of SCCM log files. This script takes a computername and a location on disk to build a dynamic parameter list and then present it to the user to choose the log file they want to parse.  Trouble is I cannot seem to get the ValidateSet portion of the dynamic parameter to provide values to the user.  In addition the script won't display the -log dynamic parameter when attempting to call the function.

When you run it for the first time you are not presented with the dynamic parameter Log as I mentioned above. If you then use -log and then hit tab you’ll get the command completer for the files in the directory you are in. Not what you’d expect; you'd expect that it would present you the Logfile names that were gathered during the dynamic parameter execution.

**PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012**

**So the question is how do I get PowerShell to present the proper Validate set items to the user?**

[image]

If you issue one of the items in the error log you get the proper behavior: 
[image]

Here are the two functions that i use to make this possible:

```
function Get-CCMLog
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]$ComputerName = '$env:computername', [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]$path = 'c:\windows\ccm\logs')
    DynamicParam
    {
        $ParameterName = 'Log'
        if($path.ToCharArray() -contains ':')
        {

            $FilePath = "\\$ComputerName\$($path -replace ':','$')"
            if(test-path $FilePath)
            {
                $logs = gci "$FilePath\*.log"
                $LogNames = $logs.basename

                $logAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
                $logAttribute.Position = 2
                $logAttribute.Mandatory = $true
                $logAttribute.HelpMessage = 'Pick A log to parse'                

                $logCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
                $logCollection.add($logAttribute)

                $logValidateSet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($LogNames)
                $logCollection.add($logValidateSet)

                $logParam = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName,[string],$logCollection)

                $logDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
                $logDictionary.Add($ParameterName,$logParam)
                return $logDictionary
            }
        }
    }
    begin {
        # Bind the parameter to a friendly variable
        $Log = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
    }

    process {
        # Your code goes here
        #dir -Path $Path
        $sb2 = "$((Get-ChildItem function:get-cmlog).scriptblock)`r`n"
        $sb1 = [scriptblock]::Create($sb2)
        $results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $sb1 -ArgumentList "$path\$log.log"
        [PSCustomObject]@{"$($log)Log"=$results}
    }
}
function Get-CMLog
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=0,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias("FullName")]
    $Path,
    $tail =10
    )
    PROCESS
    {

        if(($Path -isnot [array]) -and (test-path $Path -PathType Container) )
        {
            $Path = Get-ChildItem "$path\*.log"
        }

        foreach ($File in $Path)
        {
            if(!( test-path $file))
            {
                $Path +=(Get-ChildItem "$file*.log").fullname
            }
            $FileName = Split-Path -Path $File -Leaf
            if($tail)
            {
                $lines = Get-Content -Path $File -tail $tail 
            }
            else {
                $lines = get-cotnet -path $file
            }
            ForEach($l in $lines ){
                $l -match '\<\!\[LOG\[(?<Message>.*)?\]LOG\]\!\>\<time=\"(?<Time>.+)(?<TZAdjust>[+|-])(?<TZOffset>\d{2,3})\"\s+date=\"(?<Date>.+)?\"\s+component=\"(?<Component>.+)?\"\s+context="(?<Context>.*)?\"\s+type=\"(?<Type>\d)?\"\s+thread=\"(?<TID>\d+)?\"\s+file=\"(?<Reference>.+)?\"\>' | Out-Null
                    if($matches)
                    {
                        $UTCTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($("$($matches.date) $($matches.time)$($matches.TZAdjust)$($matches.TZOffset/60)"),"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffz", $null, "AdjustToUniversal")
                        $LocalTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($("$($matches.date) $($matches.time)"),"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", $null)
                    }
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        UTCTime = $UTCTime
                        LocalTime = $LocalTime
                        FileName = $FileName
                        Component = $matches.component
                        Context = $matches.context
                        Type = $matches.type
                        TID = $matches.TI
                        Reference = $matches.reference
                        Message = $matches.message
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos to you for trying to use `DynamicParam`.  I believe you'd need to have a `[ValidateSet()]` attribute added to `-Log` with the range of files you gathered first for it to be available in the tab-select.

Comment: I think this post should help you. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2014/06/09/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter/

Comment: @persistent13 that is what is used as the boiler plate for my script.. thanx for reminding me of where the link was.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue. When I tab completed, it was showing the correct options `-Log`. Sorry, but its hard to troubleshoot if I can't replicate. Best of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have all the dynamic logic inside scriptblock in the if statement, and it handles the parameter addition only if the path provided contains a semicolon (':'). 
You could change it to something like:

```
if($path.ToCharArray() -contains ':') {
    $FilePath = "\\$ComputerName\$($path -replace ':','$')"
} else {
    $FilePath = $path
}
```

and continue your code from there

Comment: Thank you for the solution. That seemed to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

PS 6 can do a dynamic [ValidateSet] with a class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#dynamic-validateset-values